# Firebase IE 9 storage access denied

Tags: firebase, internet-explorer-9, storage, firebase-storage

All other versions >IE9 work as expected as well as chrome/safari/firefox and I'm hosting locally with pushstate server the only think I can think of is IE9 is giving cross domain errors? I am using IE11 with dev tools in 9 emulation mode to test IE. I read a similar issue that was resolved by updating firebase but I am on 3.6

[image]

Each error is an attempt to get the photo from firebase url.
Any thoughts on what else to check or do?

** Update -- The call to getDownloadUrl from the storage ref results in access denied prior to returning the promise. And the error results from firebase.storage.js I also submitted a bug request. I've tried following the CORS setup with no change and the storage rules are properly set; hence why they work in all other versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Firebase Storage JS Dev)

The Firebase Storage JS library **does not support IE9**.

[**EDIT:** supported browser information is now available in our [Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/ENVIRONMENTS.md)]

We decided to not support IE9 in the Firebase Storage JS library for a few reasons:

- no Blob/TypedArray support, so designing a reasonable upload interface is difficult
- lackluster CORS support, which requires elaborate workarounds
- low market share

As a result you'll get CORS errors if you try to use the library in IE9. IE10 and later should work though.

Comment: Is there somewhere else I can see this information that it isn't supported?

Comment: Not yet, but I'll talk to the rest of the team and get that information published somewhere appropriate (in our docs or the SDK github repo, probably).

Comment: We now document which environments (+ browsers) are supported for the web SDK here on the Github repo https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/ENVIRONMENTS.md